# Element UI - Table with nested data - How to loop a property

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using last version of `vue-js` and `element-ui` whose documentation can be found [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table).

#### Context

I want to display a table containing some information about  `interested` and `attending` people for a given `date` and `room`

#### Issue

I do not manage to display the `attending` and `interested` for each `room` and for each `date`.

The main problem is how to loop through each room

https://jsfiddle.net/k7Lzv38b/

#### Data

```
tableData: [{
        date: 'Jan 2017',
        rooms: [{
          name: 'Room A',
          attending: 10,
          interested: 5
        }, {
          name: 'Room B',
          attending: 10,
          interested: 0
        }]
      }, {
        date: 'Feb 2017',
        rooms: [{
          name: 'Room A',
          attending: 10,
          interested: 5
        }, {
          name: 'Room B',
          attending: 10,
          interested: 0
        }]
      }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: [{
        date: 'Jan 2017',
        rooms: [{
          name: 'Room A',
          attending: 10,
          interested: 5
        }, {
          name: 'Room B',
          attending: 5,
          interested: 10
        }]
      }, {
        date: 'Feb 2017',
        rooms: [{
          name: 'Room A',
          attending: 0,
          interested: 5
        }, {
          name: 'Room B',
          attending: 5,
          interested: 15
        }]
      }, {
        date: 'Mar 2017',
        rooms: [{
          name: 'Room B',
          attending: 5
        }]
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rooms() {
      let rooms = {}
      this.tableData.forEach(row => {
        row.rooms.forEach(room => {
          rooms[room.name] = 1
        })
      })
      return Object.keys(rooms)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    cellFormatter(row, col) {
      let key = JSON.parse(col.property)
      let d = row.rooms.find(r => r.name === key.room)
      if (d && d[key.property]) {
        return d[key.property]
      }
      return '0 '
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.0.5/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.0.5/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class='container'>
      <el-table :data="tableData">
        <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" align="center"></el-table-column>
        <el-table-column label="Rooms" align="center">
          <el-table-column :label="room" prop="rooms" align="center" v-for="room in rooms" key="room">
            <el-table-column label="Attending" :prop="JSON.stringify({room, property:'attending'})" align="center" :formatter="cellFormatter">
            </el-table-column>
            <el-table-column label="Intereted" :prop="JSON.stringify({room, property:'interested'})" align="center" :formatter="cellFormatter">
            </el-table-column>
          </el-table-column>
        </el-table-column>
      </el-table>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much!!! is this documented somewhere? this "formatter" usage

Comment: it is in http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table `formatter` `function that formats cell content` `Function(row, column, cellValue)`

Comment: This is a nice complete(!), but I would rename `renderCell` as `formatter` (or similar), because you're using method signature `Function(row, column, cellValue, index)`. Render functions has different meaning, since we're only formatting scalar value (i.e. not HTML).
Also, *there is* a [`renderCell` method **that actually is like a Vue Render function**](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/table/src/table-column.js#L110)   `Function(h, { column, $index })` unfortunately, only **render-header** method is overridable. See also what @[michiel-zoer] does below.

Comment: Thanks @renoirb for pointing that out; I've updated the function name.

Answer (score 2):

To show nested data without looping use:

```
columns: [
  { prop: 'user_id', label: 'User ID' },
  { prop: 'market', label: 'Market ID', render: row => row.market.mkt_id },
  { prop: 'market', label: 'Pair',  render: row => row.market.mkt_name },
  { prop: 'exchange', label: 'Exchange ID', render: row => row.exchange.exch_id },
  { prop: 'exchange', label: 'Exchange', render: row => row.exchange.exch_name }
]
```

JSON:

```
{
  "user_id": 4,
  "type_id": 1,
  "market": {
        "id": 270,
        "mkt_id": 5946,
        "mkt_name": "AEX",
  },
  "exchange": {
        "id": 5,
        "exch_id": 15,
        "exch_name": "NL",
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a nice solution ! Would you be able to show us a full example with jsfiddle to see how it applies ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two rooms: A and B,
maybe you can simple use this 'prop' for the columns:

```
prop="rooms[0].attending"
prop="rooms[0].interested"
```

index 0 for room A and index 1 for room B